# Index was outside bounds of array in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is just a piece of my code, but it's causing me issues. The intended purpose of the code is to take the users input and make it the size of the array. However, it is giving me the error 'index was outside bounds of array' not matter what value I enter.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System

Module numbers
    Sub Main()
        'index decides number of candidates.
        Dim index as integer
        Dim candidate(index) as integer

        Console.Write("Please enter the number of candidates in the election: ")
        index=Convert.toInt32(Console.Readline())

        Do Until candidate(index) >= 0
            Console.Write(" Enter the name of candidate: ")
            candidate(index)=Convert.toInt32(Console.Readline())

            candidate(index) -=1
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few problems here.

Firstly, you need to initialise your array **after** you know how big it is.

Secondly, you will find a For loop is easier than a Do loop for implementing the logic, as you don't need to keep track of the loop counter manually.

Finally, you are converting your candidate names to an integer. Most people's names are not numeric!

```
Sub Main()
    'index decides number of candidates.
    Dim index as integer

    Console.Write("Please enter the number of candidates in the election: ")
    index=Convert.toInt32(Console.Readline())

    ' We now know how big the array needs to be so you can initialise it.
    Dim candidate(index) as integer

    ' We use a For loop so that we don't have to worry about the 
    ' loop counter ourselves.
    For i As Integer = 0 to (index - 1)
        Console.Write(" Enter the name of candidate: ")
        ' Your candidate names appear to be an integer - 
        ' Surely that's not right??! I think you meant
        ' candidate(i) = Console.Readline()
        candidate(i)=Convert.toInt32(Console.Readline())
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, I'm used to putting my thoughts together at the beginning, so moving the array never occured to me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the size of the array when `index` still equals 0.  You need to move the array declaration to below the line where `index` is set to the entered value:

```
' ...
Console.Write("Please enter the number of candidates in the election: ")
index=Convert.toInt32(Console.Readline())
Dim candidate(index) as integer
' ...
```

As far as the loop, I'm totally confused as to what you are trying to accomplish, but it certainly looks like there's a better way to do it.  If you were to explain your intention for that loop, I could probably suggest a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly, you are using Index to give candidate a size. but you use it, before it gets the value from the console. So it has a size of 0.
Move the Dim state after the readline.
Also, you shoild use something like integer.tryparse to read the console.

Additionally, I do not understand the purpose of your do while ,
a for i =  to index would be clearer...